# 139 updates wont update

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I can't seem to upgrade the 139 packages I can upgrade. It is saying I am not connected to the internet yet I am typing this to you on the same computer.

I have deleted most of the errors as it shows the same IP all the time and I am not sure if it is mine or not.

Here is the error message I get :

```
Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icedtea-web/icedtea-netx-common_1.2-2ubuntu1.2_all.deb 404  Not Found
```

**Any** ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually live in Australia? This could be the wrong server or messed up sources.

Answer (score 1):

First try `sudo apt-get update` to make sure your trying to fetch the most recent versions of the packages. It's not uncommon for updates to be updated more then a few times, in between the time that you run updates.

Next try `sudo apt-get upgrade` from the command line. It will give you more details.

If, during either step. you get errors about 404s like the one you posted. It doesn't mean your not connected to the internet, just that the server your tring to download from can't find the file your truing to download. Perhaps it isn't up to date yet (it's still mirroring) or perhaps your out of date.

If the problem continues try opening `update-manager` going to settings and changing your "Download From" to either "Main Server" or choosing a server from another region. They should all have the same files, but perhaps the AU server is having some turkey day issues.